# how to use regex in grafana variables for dashboards

Tags: regex, grafana, grafana-variable

I am trying to create a grafana dashboard for cassandra and I need assistance how to filter a variable from the metric output.

Grafana Query:
`label_values(collectd_dse_histogram_p98{cluster_name=~"$cluster",dse=~"org.apache.cassandra.metrics.table.read_latency.*.*"},dse)`

Regex tried: `org.apache.cassandra.metrics.table.read_latency.(.*)`

Output I am getting is in the format `keyspace.table_name`.  Need assistance how a Regex expression be formatted to extract only `keyspace` from the output.

Getting Output as "keyspace"."table_name"

Need only "keyspace" as output variable.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot to help us visualise what is currently configured?

Comment: Also, an example of sample input and corresponding output would be helpful.

Comment: Try this: `org.apache.cassandra.metrics.table.read_latency.([^.]*)`

Comment: You can use either `/org.apache.cassandra.metrics.table.read_latency.([^.]*)/` or `org.apache.cassandra.metrics.table.read_latency.([^.]*).*`. Also, you should probably escape all the dots in your pattern.

Answer (score 1):

To match `keyspace` in `org.apache.cassandra.metrics.table.read_latency.keyspace.table_name` proper regex is [`org\.apache\.cassandra\.metrics\.table\.read_latency\.(\[^.\]*)\..*`](https://regex101.com/r/swmxQF/1):
It matches predefined prefix (while escaping dots, as the have special meaning in regex), and then it captures everything till next dot into a group.

Please notice that regex here matches full string.

`/org\.apache\.cassandra\.metrics\.table\.read_latency\.([^.]*)/` might also work work, but in this case notice that regex is surrounded by `/`.

Difference is due to Grafana [treating regexes differently](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/main/packages/grafana-data/src/text/string.ts#L34) depending on if they are enclosed in `/.../` or not. Those without slashes are added with anchors `^` and `$` automatically.

[image]